# How to fix transition of transform on IE with property: transform: scaleX(-1) translateY(-50%);

Tags: css-transitions

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: the image of the button

[2] There are styles for this button. Please looking at the line (.btnDefault:hover:after).

```css
.btnDefault {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 46px 0 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 160px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 51px 0px rgba(88, 49, 33, .4);
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btnDefault:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 25px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPcvP.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btnDefault:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}

.btnDefault:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(-1) translateY(-50%);
}
[3] this is button HTML
```

```html
<a class="btnDefault">VIEW MORE</a>
```

Comment: For IE you may need to use `-webkit-` and `-ms-` prefix

Comment: It's not working too!